# How to write release note with Gitlab CI/CD for app upload?

Tags: flutter, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

Want to upload flutter release app to the app center with Gitlab CI/CD.
I want to know is how to add or write script for **app release note** within `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Here is my example deploy script and how to make it.

```
deploy_android_to_appcenter:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - XXXX/XXXX
  script:
    - appcenter login --token $APPCENTER_API_TOKEN
    - appcenter distribute release -f build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk -g Collaborators —app [Name]/[App-Name]
  tags:
    - branchName
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from git hub issue.
By adding `--release-notes "$(cat release_notes.*)"` inside `appcenter distribute release` shell command. And need to create **release_notes.md** inside the root of project. But always update manually that file for every build.

Example:

```
deploy_android_to_appcenter:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - dev_branch
  script:
    - appcenter login --token $APPCENTER_API_TOKEN
    - appcenter distribute release --app [name]/[app] --file build/app/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk --group Collaborators --release-notes "$(cat release_notes.*)"
  tags:
    - dev
```

Answer (score -1):

To add a script for app release notes within your GitLab CI/CD configuration file (.gitlab-ci.yml), you can use a combination of GitLab CI variables and scripting.

```
stages:
  - build
  - release

variables:
  APP_VERSION: "1.0.0"
  RELEASE_NOTES: "Initial release"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - flutter build apk --release

release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - echo $RELEASE_NOTES > release_notes.txt
    - git tag -a v$APP_VERSION -F release_notes.txt
    - git push --tags
```

Comment: How can I export $RELEASE_NOTES variable from release_notes.txt in shell? I search the way to do this, but I am not clear... please answer or exporting method to do this.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow.  It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since many of your last seven answers today appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.